# findByIdAndDelete doesn't actually delete a document, just nulls the value for each key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Newbie here using mongoose in node.js/express with MongoDB to try to build my own wedding website. I have in my app.js:

```
var Guest           =       require("./models/guest");

...

app.delete("/guests/:id", (req, res)=>{
    Guest.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, deletedGuest)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/guests");
        } else {
            console.log("deleted: " + deletedGuest);
            res.redirect("/guests");
            
        }
    })
})
```

with the model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var guestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    isComing: Boolean,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Guest", guestSchema);
```

And there's an html table of guests with a delete button next to each one. So what happens is if I try to delete a guest by clicking the button next to their name, it sets that guest's name, email, and isComing to null, but doesn't delete it. In other words, for the guest:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef811d5ea932d06d38537f5"), "name" : "Steve Stevenson", "email" : "steve@steve.com", "isComing" : true, "__v" : 0 }
```

If I press "delete," I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef811d5ea932d06d38537f5"), "name" : null, "email" : null, "isComing" : null, "__v" : 0 }
```

The ID stays the same, it just removes all the values from the other keys, except the "__v" field. (Incidentally, I also have no idea what that is). Nothing gets logged in the console- no error or deleted guest. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Other general advice is also welcome-- I'm trying to learn here.

Comment: In first glance you're not casing `req.params.id` to `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` so it weird anything is even happening as the match should fail.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was I forgot to set method-override. So it was just sending a blank post request with that ID— hence the null values for each key. Whoops.